# Eigen3, How to achieve polymorphism with dense and sparse matrices?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

I want to build an array which contains pointers to both large sparse and dense matrices. Then, I desire to operate on them using polymorphism and avoiding to copy/allocate large portions of memory. E.g.

```
std::vector<UnkownType*> matrices;

matrices.emplace_back(get_large_dense_matrix_ptr());
matrices.emplace_back(get_large_sparse_matrix_ptr());

Eigen::MatrixXd result(known_size, known_size);
for(mat : matrices){
   result+=*mat;
}
```

What should be the `UnkownType` type?
I thought in the alternative of using a variant of references or reference wrappers, but this is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++17, you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

```
using matrix_variant = std::variant<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>;

std::vector<matrix_variant> matrices;

matrices.emplace_back(Eigen::MatrixXd::Zeros(10, 10).eval());
matrices.emplace_back(Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>{});

Eigen::MatrixXd result;
for(const matrix_variant& matrix: matrices) {
    if(std::holds_alternative<Eigen::MatrixXd>(matrix)) {
        const Eigen::MatrixXd& dense = std::get<Eigen::MatrixXd>(matrix);
        result += dense;
    } else if(std::holds_alternative<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>(matrix)) {
        const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& sparse =
              std::get<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>(matrix);
        result += sparse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but the problem here is that I have to copy large pieces of data.

Comment: @MiguelitoValdez I don't think you are explaining properly what you are actually doing but if you don't want the variant to hold the matrix directly, you can make a variant of raw pointers or ```shared_ptr```s. If you want each matrix to be a "view" into one bigger matrix, that is an entirely different question